# Change arrow type in custom style in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to define a custom style for my plots in pgfplots

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\usepackage{tikz}                        
\usepackage{pgfplots}                    
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}                

%custom style
\pgfplotsset{
    mycustomstyle axis/.style={
    axis line style={->},
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
mycustomstyle axis,
width=7cm,
height=7cm,
xtick={1,4},
ytick={1,2},
xticklabels={$x_0$,$x_1$},
yticklabels={$f(x_0)$,$f(x_1)$},
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=0,
ymax=2.5,
clip = false
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=0.75:4.2,samples=100, thick]{-5/12*x^2 +x*29/12 -1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see from the picture below it works except for the arrows that don't change appearance. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You need to swap the order of the keys `axis line style={->},axis lines=middle` because the second one overwrites the first

Comment: @percusse I tried doing that, but didn't notice any change! Now I do. Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the key order of `axis lines=middle` and `axis line style={->}`. That should fix the arrow tip issue.

Also, although you don't mention this in the question, since you specified `axis lines=middle`, you must also specify a `min` that goes below 0 for this to come into effect (i.e. having the axis lines intersect at 0). If the minimum is 0 for both axes and the 0 is where they intersect then they're not going to show any "intersection".

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}                    
\usepackage{tikz}                        
\usepackage{pgfplots}                    
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}              

%custom style
\pgfplotsset{
    mycustomstyle axis/.style={
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={->},    
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
mycustomstyle axis,
width=7cm,
height=7cm,
xtick={1,4},
ytick={1,2},
xticklabels={$x_0$,$x_1$},
yticklabels={$f(x_0)$,$f(x_1)$},
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
ymin=-2.5,
ymax=2.5,
clip = false
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=0.75:4.2,samples=100, thick]{-5/12*x^2 +x*29/12 -1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I mean the arrow tip is still "stealth" and not latex as it should be with {->}. @percusse hint solved the problem.

Comment: @Emmet Ah yes, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @Emmet Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you and thank percusse for the help.